# In ADF, extracting data using ingest feature works fine but cannot extract data using data flow. Any suggestions?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My goal:
Create a data flow with a Synapse source, some Power Query transformations, and then load the result into a Synapse sink. Data flow passes validation. When I move the data flow into a pipeline (as the only thing in the pipeline), it passes validation, and then fails in debug.

What I've tried that worked:
(1) created linked services to Azure Blob Storage and Azure Synapse Analytics,
(2) created datasets for the source and the sink,
(3) created a pipeline using the ingest feature to read data from the Synapse source, stage in the blob storage, and copy the data to the Synapse sink

What did not work:
created a data flow to read data from the Synapse source, stage in the blob storage, and copy the data to the Synapse sink. Data flow validation worked fine. I dragged and dropped the data flow onto the pipeline canvas. The pipeline validated ok but died upon debug.

I've run this two different ways, changing the account used in the linked services:

(1) using my account (Contributor status). I get an error saying I do not have permission.
I have enough permission to copy data using the ingest feature, why would I not have enough permission to copy data using a data flow?[image: This is the error I received]

(2) using an admin account. The pipeline still failed but error now refers to a master key.
[image: This is the error I received]

Answer (score 1):

As per the error you are getting it seems that ADF Data Flow is using polybase method to read data from synapse Analytics.

> The connection expects the first instruction to be preceded by the existence of a database master key for the selected Azure Synapse instance. In that case, you can use the CREATE MASTER KEY command to create a key.

**As mentioned in the error to resolve that you can Create a master key or Alter master key on the source database.**

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'strong_password'
```

OR

```
ALTER MASTER KEY REGENERATE WITH ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'strong_password';
```

you can do it directly in synapse SQL pool or run script activity before dataflow for the same .

> FYI it can be bug, I tried the same in my environment but initially I am getting same error as you but after running copy activity for the same and its successful execution the data flow is also executed successfully.
>
> Raised the issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/issues/585) for the same

**Successful Execution:**

[image]